# How to format log records created by the same function in the same way

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, logging, python-logging

Is it possible to format all log records created as a result of running a particular function in the same way?

E.g., instead of:

```
import requests
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


def foo():
    logging.info("Running foo")
    requests.get("http://www.google.com")


def bar():
    logging.info("Running bar")
    requests.get("http://www.google.com")


foo()
bar()
```

giving:

```
INFO:root:Running foo
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.google.com:80
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://www.google.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5499
INFO:root:Running bar
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.google.com:80
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://www.google.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5470
```

I want something like:

```
foo | INFO:root:Running foo
foo | DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.google.com:80
foo | DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://www.google.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5499
bar | INFO:root:Running bar
bar | DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.google.com:80
bar | DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://www.google.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5470
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is formatters. They are built in to the logging module.

```py
import logging

FORMAT = "%(funcName)s - %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"

logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=logging.DEBUG)

def foo():
    logging.info("In foo")

def bar():
    logging.info("In bar")

foo()
bar()
```

The will output:

```
foo - 2020-04-07 17:55:07,125 - INFO - In foo
bar - 2020-04-07 17:55:07,132 - INFO - In bar
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) explain all about them. You can add all sorts of custom output to each logging call.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but I'm looking for a way to also have `foo | ` and `bar |` at the start of the log records created by the `requests` moudle. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean actually. You want it to only go one level deep. No this will not do that.

Answer (score 0):

The output will look different, as in the function name will be overwritten by the called function name as seen in the bellow output.

```
    import requests
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    FORMAT = "%(funcName)20s | %(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def foo():
    logging.info(f"Starting {foo.__name__}")
    requests.get("http://www.google.com")



def bar():
    logging.info(f"Starting {bar.__name__}")
    requests.get("http://www.google.com")


foo()
bar()
```

Output:

```
             foo | INFO:root: Starting foo
       _new_conn | DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.google.com:80
   _make_request | DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool: http://www.google.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5778
             bar | INFO:root: Starting bar
       _new_conn | DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.google.com:80
   _make_request | DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool: http://www.google.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5745
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Is there any way to overwrite the function names from the requests module with `foo` and `bar` etc?

Comment: Unfortunately no; Per [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html) - `%(funcName)s Name of function containing the logging call.` and since the output (eg. ' Starting new HTTP connection...)` is from the the `get` method..